# Retrain languages in the 4e character builder?

Tags: dnd-4e, languages, dnd-4e-character-builder, retraining

Is it possible to retrain languages? How does one do this in the 4e Character Builder?

Comment: How can you "unlearn" a language and replace it with a new one?

Comment: @Jonn Same way you unlearn a skill, apparently. Reason it as the character forgetting all but a few words due to disuse, perhaps!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**RAW, No.** Retraining in 4e is limited to skills, feats, and powers. From the compendium:

> Every time a character gains a level, he or she can retrain. This involves changing one feat, power, or trained skill. Only one change is allowed per level. If the player book says to replace one of the character’s powers with a different power of a higher level, replacing the power doesn’t count as retraining. The character can still retrain a feat, some other power, or a trained skill.

The character builder will not support it as such. You can just manually go in and change a language but I would only do that with DM approval ahead of time. To do that load your character, click **2: Select Race** and then double click on your previous selected language to change it.

Comment: That's one thing I "love" about the character builder is how it doesn't seem to care about existing/unfinished characters.

Comment: The only thing I've really found wonky is sometimes you can accidentally house-rule something and its hard to undo it short of starting a new character and it doesn't like when you switch backgrounds during creation.

Comment: you can retrain themes as well.

Comment: Thanks, guys, got what I wanted from that. I've been through the whole menu, and looks like the current version doesn't have any place to change languages. If I'm wrong, feel free to flame me =)

Comment: Not within the retrain menu no, but like I said go through the menus as I described in the 2nd paragraph and you can manually change it. Again get DM approval. Lastly, the Character Builder is not a rules resource (wish it was) it has been as much as a month behind the errata in the past and there are all sorts of pre-req bugs and conflicts from time to time which aren't reflected in the actual rules.

Comment: @retrovtx If you feel this fully answered your question then please check it off as best answer. It not only gives me points, but gives them to you as well and helps signify to other users that the question is (mostly) settled.